# Safe removing of startup (manager)

Tags: dual-boot

lenovoZ570, i7 x64,8GB, 700GB, Nvidia Optimus+intel, 1366x768, win7+11.10 ubuntu+kubuntu. Until now nvidia isn´t installed or used.
Some problems, which may relay one on another or interact:

```
+ after running startup to configure grub2 strange things happen during boot or at
  shutdown
+ startup loaded 19MB but nearly nothing is to change. I choose ubuntu 30015, it is
  shown on the button but at boot only the cursor is on old recovery 30014
+ 14 entries in grub, 6 ubuntu(30012,30014,30015) 4kubuntu(30014,30015) 2win7 and 2 mem
```

So the question: **Is it possible to remove that useless "startup" without blackout?** 
It changed more than 25 places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  there was no answer, i first removed it in kubuntu with the package-manager, no problems with the deinstalling. What everbody should know, it is not only nearly useless, but holds 143 files back of actualisation!! May be this is the reason for that strange behaviour at start and shutdown. Afterwards in ubuntu, all fine.
Also i have learnt now during my attempts to change grub manually, that it is a built in defeat of grub with its 4 discrete parts or groups. So you cannot change a position, only the cursor can be not on top.

But I want from a bootloader, that i can change the position and name of OS and remove unneeded (old) entries. Both, ubuntu and kubuntu have the same name ubuntu for example!
There are win7, ubuntu and kubuntu and i don´t need more to be shown, one with a star to mark, this is the default one.
**perhaps a little prestart-screen could do this, which then calls the normaly hidden grub menu (the boring one)**
I guess lilo could do this job and calls the ubuntu-grub, the kubuntu-grub or the win-bootloader. =>In the meantime there is an inactive grub on ubuntu-partition, but seems to be called from the kubuntu-grub, so this can work.